# Vue 3 disable caching of components - previous components are now being stacked

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am developing a Vue3 application with a component that renders a D3 chart.
The problem occurs when I navigate to another page and get back to the same D3 component but with different data. The D3 charts keep on getting stacked on each other.
I am using Vue3 and found it is a bit difficult to disable caching of components but perhaps I missed some options. I wouldn't mind disabling caching completely, because most of the data is obtained from localStorage, so pretty quick anyway

Here is a sandbox to illustrate the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vuex-4-vue-router-forked-eem3ui?file=/src/components/Miserables.vue

If you click on the "Miserables" link, then to another link (Playerlist or About) and back to Miserables, you'll see the charts stacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 2 "smells" in your code:

1. you are creating and injecting `<script>` tags every time your **Miserables** component is being mounted - after multiple mountings you will have a lot of duplicate JavaScript code, pontentially poluting the global namespace (multiple times) and worse - potentially attaching multiple event handlers or setting up timers;
2. on every mounting you are creating a new SVG and appending it to the BODY - so it's not Vue's fault that you're getting multiple SVGs on the page;

Comment: Excellent suggestions Ivo, thanks. I've moved the script tags to App.vue, that should hopefully solve it. Regarding the mounting of SVG to the body, I created some a new div section and linked the SVG. That solves seeing the SVG in other pages, but if you go back, you see a duplicated chart. Interestingly, it doesn't go over 2 instances, in my own dev code i can reach a lot more charts. So now the question remains, how to disable the cache for this component? Or disable it for all components.

Comment: Like I said - there is no cache here, you are creating a new SVG in your "mounted" hook and then inserting it into the DOM. Every time you do this - there will be a new SVG in the DOM. You should first remove the old SVG before adding a new one - as explained in https://reactgo.com/d3js-remove-svg/

Comment: beforeUnmount() {
    console.log('beforeUnmount! resetting');
    this.svg.selectAll('*').remove();
  }, did the trick, thanks Ivo!